# UITableviewcell containing UITextfield hides while scrolling UITableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

There are 7 **Static** **UITableviewcell** with each containing 1 **UITextField** in **UITableviewcontroller**. When keyboard opens for the *4th* **UITextField** and scrolls down, The last 2 UITableviewcell hides *unfortunately*. `lastCell.isHidden = false` has been tried but not working anyhow.

Comment: Share code please

Comment: All textfields and cell outlets are taken. not much coding done.

Comment: call cell.textfeild.resignFirstResponder() in cellForRowAtIndexpath

Comment: that I've done in handling toolbar and Tableview.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

Comment: Better way to handle text input inside any scrollable view is to use https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, I was altering the height of UITableviewcell with UITableviewAutomaticDimension with the help of estimated row height calculation. So, for static cell, **UITableviewAutomaticDimension** doesn't *work*. I gave each height of the cell fixed and it worked!